# How do I change the load balancer attached to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deleted the original load balancer that was associated with my environment and used another.  Now the environment shows red although the instances in the target group are healthy and the app is operating as it should.

I have looked through the documentation but cannot see a way to update this.

How can I register the new load balancer with the environment/get a green status?

Please see my attached image to health elastic beanstalk -> health.[elastic beanstalk health](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iamkf.png)

Comment: Fix it via EB console. I mean create ELB and update env.

Comment: But my target group is working and healthy, i can't understand why elastic beanstalk is red.  i have added a link to the screenshot of my eb health.

Comment: Because Elastic Beanstalk is intended to to provide a convenient way to start up multiple components at once and provide monitoring for them. If you decide to shut down one of those components then it can't do that monitoring, because it doesn't know anything about the new component that you started.

Comment: Bob, have you confirmed your Load Balancer and your EB instance(s) are all in the save Availability Zones? If your instances are in an availability zone which is not enabled for your Load Balancer, you will not be able to select them when configuring the instances for your Target Group.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the Load Balancing Target Group that's being used
2. On it's "Health Check" tab, find everything is set correctly, meaning, when an http request is hit, the deployed app is supposed to respond with 200 status code

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you have to first "rebuild your environment" under "actions" dropdown button and then do the following:

1. Go to EC2 service page and on the left menu, under Load Balancer, click on "Target Group"
2. Select the right "Target Group" in the list
3. Under the "Statuts check" tab, at the bottom, click on "modify" button
4. at the bottom of modal window, you will have "success code" and there you just have to replace the value with "200,302".

That means you are allowing the 302 response code which is used for redirection by the load balancer, and then health check will update to green